# Limits of view, ignore whats behind view

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, angle, radians

there is a lots of material about this, its just my english skills of issue that mostlikely now confuses me.

I have a character, position x, y. It's angle is *a*. *a* is in angles (0 - 359). View of sight is 180.
Currently *"left"* causes *a = a - 5* and *"right"*  *a = a + 5*. After this i check if *a* < 0 or > 359 and if so, ill correct it.

Maybe i should fix my a to work somehow else, since i cant figure out the the view of sight (180).
If *a* = 45, then view of sight should be between 315 and 135. If its between 350 and 170.

Im in need to have a angle for my character with what it would be easy to raycast the view of sight, 180.

Maybe radians or something would help. Please help me out.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is the problem to be solved, but anyway, to get the range of visible angles (not sure if there's a better term in English) around `a` can be found by subtracting 90 from `a` and adding 90 to `a`. If subtracting gives you a negative number, just add 360. If adding gives you a number greater than 360, just subtract 360.

Comment: If there are any languages you know better than English, maybe you can try to find a forum in one of those languages.